# Call to a member function set_charset() on boolean

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$dbhost = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? 'localhost' : 'localhost';
$dbuser = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? 'ppapcom_ppap' : 'ppapcom_ppap'; //'trs-camb_admin';
$dbpwd = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? 'it@a2z' : 'it@a2z';
$dbname = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? 'ppapcom_ppapadmin' : 'ppapcom_ppapadmin'; //'trs-camb_motdb';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8");
if (!$conn) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); 
}
```

Comment: The connection failed check for errors before trying to use it.

Comment: wondering even why you're using ternaries and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to start with. Try a standard method; if that works then your method failed.

Comment: yeah, it's was fail, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to your database failed, you can use:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('The error was: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

To determine what the error was, place it BEFORE the set_charset() call.